# What is rational integral function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

The author of the book I am referring assumes two **rational integral functions** as shown below

$p_0\cdot x^n+p_1\cdot x^{(n-1)}+p_2\cdot x^{(n-2)}+...+p_n$

$q_0\cdot x^n+q_1\cdot x^{(n-1)}+q_2\cdot x^{(n-2)}+...+q_n$

Is this term old and he means **real** functions ?; if not, what is meant by rational integral function ?, rational function, integral function ?

Comment: Probably just means "polynomial". Or maybe, "polynomial with rational coefficients".

Comment: @GerryMyerson, thankx

Comment: This book also defines the term to mean 'polynomial' 

https://books.google.ca/books?id=tIESDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA530&lpg=PA530&dq=%22integral+rational+function%22&source=bl&ots=EysI6Imab8&sig=quwera92wRJ-XKKnn0vvnC1upDs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwibusGn8qDXAhUFxYMKHRLwDGUQ6AEIVTAH#v=onepage&q=%22integral%20rational%20function%22&f=false

Answer (score 5):

The heading of chap.4 of *Modern Algebra* 1 (1949) by Van der Waerden is "Polynomials" in English, and "Ganze rationale Funktionen" in German (http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-662-41906-9_5). 
According to Bieberbach (*Algebra*, 1928) a rational analytic expression is an integral rational function if there are no variable divisors.

Answer (score 5):

I think this would be helpful:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Reference: Handbook of Mathematics and Computational Science
By John W. Harris, Horst Stöcker.