# what is the modern name for this type of function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis

every algebraic rational integral function of one variable quantity can be divided into real factors with various degree

what is the modern name for this type of function is it polynomial?

Comment: I find it really hard to understand what you are asking. Could you give an example of such a function? Or, since you are looking for a "modern" name, what is the old name? (Note: I didn't vote to close since I think it is on-topic - terminology question - provided the formulation is improved)

Comment: He is asking what is algebraic rational integral function.

Comment: ChenyangYu is right this is what is referred to as a polynomial or power series if you want the general solution. [What is rational integral function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1275194/what-is-rational-integral-function) Refers to the same thing.

Comment: The OP should define what they mean by "algebraic rational integral function of one variable quantity".  It is very clear what a (univariate) polynomial with coefficients from a ring means.  Polynomial is not an especially "modern name".  It has a history in mathematics going back to the late 17th century.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my understanding, this sentence is saying that a polynomial of one variable can be factored into real factors with different degrees. Most likely the word "rational integral function" is a just a translation of "Ganzrationale Funktion" in German, which is equivalent to "polynomial".

Here is a wikipedia link on this:  https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganzrationale_Funktion

Comment: this what I think

Comment: Yes, you are correct.