# Case of Integral rational function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, fractions

In the older literature they use the term *integral rational function*. I did google search, math/SE search etc and see that mostly *integral rational function* is interpreted to mean "*polynomial*".

But when we read in the older literature that the *integral rational function* $f=f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ is required to be homogeneous of degree zero in the $x_k$'s, shouldn't it have the form

$$f=\frac{x_9}{x_{15}}$$
or
$$f=\frac{x_1 x_5}{x_2 x_7}+\left( \frac{x_1 x_2 x_3}{x_4 x_5 x_6} \right)^3$$

for example? It seems the only way it is homogeneous of degree zero is to have fractions appear in $f$.

The problem I see is that a *polynomial* by definition does not have variables in the denominator.

Is then an *integral rational function* always a *polynomial*? What are the properties of integral rational functions.

Comment: The answers to your two questions are no, and too long to answer for a single question.

Comment: Which literature are you referring to?

Comment: Don Thousand, the two examples I gave, are they correct examples of homogeneous integral rational functions of degree 0?

Comment: Chappers, older literature that refers to homogeneous integral rational functions,, the American Journal of Math from the early 1900s has articles that use this term

Comment: Relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1275194/what-is-rational-integral-function

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this thread but there the integral rational function is said to be a only a polynomial

Comment: They even say there shouldn't be variable divisors